Validar si determinado numero esta presente en una cadena String en Ansible
De que manera puedo comprobar si un numero determinado Ejem: 12345 se encuentra presente en una cadena String utilizando filtros jinja en Ansible y en base a ello realizar una determinada accion.
Ejemplo de String : "Saturday-13-July-04:02:41 YA EXISTE SERVIDOR EJECUTANDOSE : 12345"

Hola, Alan. ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento?

De momento solo he utilizado el filtro de search

Te dejo 2 opciones una con JINJA2 y otra con un when de ansible simple, ya que si lo que deseas es hacer otra accion creo que el when simple te sera mucho mas util y sencillo.
---
  - hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: no
    vars:
      - Stringvar: "Hola en este texto tenemos los numeros 1234567 y 12345 en el texto"
    tasks:
      - name: "Debug"
        debug:
          msg: |
            {% if '12345' in Stringvar %}
              "El numero 12345 esta en la cadena"
            {% else %}
              "El numero 12345 no esta en la cadena"
            {% endif %}

      - name: "Debug 2"
        debug:
          msg: "Esta en la cadena"
        when: "'12345' in Stringvar"



Muchas gracias amigo agradezco el apoyo me sirvio de mucho.. Saludos
